# I have tried this code but it it not working.though all the field are null but it still take action.code is given below

Tags: java, user-interface

This is my code:

```
if( ((f_NameText.getText())!=null )
    &&((l_NameText.getText())!=null)
    &&((u_NameText.getText())!=null)
    &&((newMembersPassword.getPassword())!=null)
  ) {
    newMembersButton.addActionListener(new NewJoinButtonHandler());
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should not ask like this... Read how to ask and how to format first.

Comment: do you now the answer .actually i am new in this group .

Answer (score 0):

getText will never return null. can you try getText().length() == 0 check instead of null check?